# Sagemaker Pipelines | Pass artifacts between two processing steps

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to execute two processing steps (both custom scripts) in a pipeline one after the other and pass an artifact from one step to the next. Can someone show me an example of how I can do it? I have only found examples of Processing Step + Training Step.

Br,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass artifacts between processing jobs the same way you do it between Processing and Training jobs.

Take the output of a processing job and supply it to `ProcessingInput` of the next processing job.